# How do I provide an AngularFirestoreDocument to a component using route parameters through a service?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm just learning about firebase and I seem to have caught a snag in my understanding of how it works with Observables. If I have a component `ItemDetailComponent` which leverages a service `ItemService` to access a firestore document why is this code only returning null when the document exists?

Here is the component's onInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.item$ = this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      return this.service.getItem(params.get('id'));
    });
    // this works when accessed from the template
    this.forcedItem$ = this.afs.doc('items/oll71FoVdq0wpLAM85HO').valueChanges();
  }
```

Here is the service method:

```
  getItem(ItemId: string | number) {
    this.ItemDoc = this.afs.doc<any>(`items/${itemId}`);
    return this.ItemDoc.valueChanges();
  }
```

Here is the component's template:

```
  <span>Doesn't work: {{item$ | async | json}}</span>
  <hr/>
  <span>works: {{forcedItem$ | async | json}}</span>
```

The only difference from the Angular docs is that I'm returning an `Observable`
 instead of a POJO.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
        this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
        return this.service.getHeroes(); // This returns a POJO, I'm returning an Observable
      });
  }
```

In any case switchMap doesn't return anything but `null` in my case. Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Catch your parameter using an Obervable and then make your Firestore calls from inside it

Define an ActiveRoute on your contructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Now go get your route parameter and then call your service

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
           this.item$ = this.service.getItem(params['id']); 
    });
}
```

Comment: I get a TypeScript error:
Argument of type '(params: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: even if I just return `Observable.create({})` I still get `null` in the rendered HTML

Comment: I edited my answer, could you try it? 
Hope to help now